# Tips for using CiviCRM on Amazon EC2

Tags: installation, amazon

Is someone running CiviCRM on the Amazon EC2 (Part of the Amazon Webservices)? I would like to know:

- What instance type is selected?
- Is the operating system AWS Linux (supported by Amazon)?
- Are there other Amazon Services in use (for example Amazon RDS, of Amazon EC2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not running Civi on EC2 but I am running other things on it and I can assure you it behaves just like any Linux server.

Personally I prefer Ubuntu to AWS Linux (it's one of the choices) - but Civi will run on either. I just like to use ubuntu because it's familiar and better documented. I use Apache web server (which you have to install using "apt-get") but you can use other web servers if you prefer.

My instance type seems to be "t2.micro" but I suspect it's the default - I don't know what it means, so I won't have picked it on purpose.

Takeaway message - no specific settings are needed for Civi over and above being a standard Linux server with a sensible web server running on it!

Comment: Thanks naomi. This proofs that it is technical possible, but I am also interested in the costs and the support.

Answer (score 1):

@Kainuk, I've implemented three instances of CiviCRM / WordPress / LAMP on AWS, and am in the process of converting two of them to public production, the third has been running private production for about 14 months now.  All are implemented on t2.micro instances on Ubuntu (14.04.3 - LTS).  Each has a very small audience (regional < 1,000 expected public users and < 10 backend / database users per instance) and is purpose built for a specific not-for-profit organization and its audience. @naomi says "no specific settings are needed for CiviCRM;" I agree.  That said, it can be challenging, because there is not a large community in this space.  The support you get is the general support available to CiviCRM and WordPress, not so much directly for AWS.  So far, that has not been a major issue.

I am using these AWS Services:  EC2 - compute / memory (EBS),  Networking - VPC and Route53 - DNS, Cloudwatch - Basic monitoring, and IAM - User management.  The first year of use is basically free, beyond that, for my groups, using reserved t2.micro instances on a 3 year basis, costs run ~USD 100.00 / year, each.  With current low loading, performance has been entirely satisfactory.

I have put up a general [how-to article](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=277970947) on the CiviCRM wiki, which provides more details.  I'm eager to continue the conversation and wish you success in your efforts.

Comment: Thanks @dvhirst. So you did prove that it is possible to run CiviCRM successfully on the smallest Amazon instance. I suppose you mean with a small audience 1000 contacts and not thousand users.

Comment: Well, this is an old question, but here's the answer:  The configuration is working on a t2.micro instance, and so far, the service levels are OK.  The instance has 1 GB main storage (about 40% occupied, 1 GB swap, 0% used, and 12 GB of general SSD storage, about 40% in use).